# BMC Remedy user 7.5 Could i make a macro that can read a .csv file?

Tags: csv, macros, remedy

I need to create a macro in BMC remedy user 7.5, that can read a csv file and update all items contain in the csv file?

Is it possible ?

I have to make a large bundle of item and edit there location.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a macro.  But you can use the Remedy Import Tool.  It has the capability to automatically import a CSV file.  It takes as inputs a mapping file and the CSV file (with full paths of course).

Check out the guide titled "BMC Remedy Action Request System 7.6.04 Configuration Guide".  You should find what you're looking for there.

Best of luck,

Mike